# Different jquery behavior on normal vs. inspection mode in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to use sticky header on my website, so navigation remains on top of page when user scrolls down. Here some implementation of jquery:

```
if (window_y > scroll_critical) {
        if ( !$hContainer.hasClass("header-fixed") ) {
            $hContainer.addClass("header-fixed");
            if ( search_visible ) {
                $('.nav-search-container').removeClass('search-visible');
                $('#search').css({'opacity': 0, display: 'none' });
                form_search_over = false;
                $('.form-search').removeClass('form-search-over');
            }
            if ( $navWide.length ) {
                $navWide.css('margin-left', $('div.logo-container').width());
                if ( $navWide.height() > $('.logo-container').height() ) {
                    $navWide.css('margin-top', -$navWide.height());
                    $('.logo-container').css('height', $navWide.height());
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ( $hContainer.hasClass("header-fixed") ) {
            $hContainer.removeClass("header-fixed");
            if ( search_visible ) {
                $('.nav-search-container').addClass('search-visible');
                $('#search').css({'opacity': 1, display: 'block' });
                form_search_over = false;
                $('.form-search').removeClass('form-search-over');
            }
            if ( $navWide.length ) {
                $navWide.css('margin-left', '');
                $navWide.css('margin-top', '');
                $('.logo-container').css('height', '');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works on Safari and Firefox well, but not on Chrome. What happen was, when vertical position met the requirement to apply sticky header, it just bounced back to top and display
just normal header. What made me more confused was, it worked as I expected when I was on inspection mode (Inspect Element on right click). I also tested on different page, and I noticed that it worked one some pages and didn't work on some other pages. Is there anything wrong with above code that potentially cause the issue on Chrome particularly?

Comment: Apparently, adding <h1> tag in the content resolved the issue, but I still do not get why missing this tag caused the issue only in chrome, because it's totally unrelated with the script